# Joomla: How to identify components on the front page?

Tags: joomla

I know that you can view the position of modules that appear on the page by using '?tp=1'.

But let's say I don't know what each module that appears on the front page is. That means I don't know their ID, their name or what they are referred to as at the back end. I just saw the front page and used to '?tp=1' to see their positions.

Now in order to move them around using the back-end, how can find the name or ID or a certain module that appears on the front page?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that there is no way to organize modules by the physical position on the front page..

Answer (score 1):

First find a module by a position. For instance, if it's on the right side of frontpage, you can sort all modules in the administrator panel by 'right' position. 
Then, click on each module (edit) and look, in which pages they appear. If you have smth like Home page, and it's selected, it means it appears in your frontpage.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer. I will try this out. I guess this is the easiest possible to way to recognize the modules that appear on Joomla pages in order to refer to them at the back end?

Comment: actually, this did not work out because it seems that there is no way to organize modules by the physical position on the front page :(